# Not able to SOQL archive articles in workbench

Tags: articles

Not able to SOQL archive articles in workbench for a particle article type alone. So i am not able to retrieve articles from my production. Please do provide a solution if anyone knows. ASAP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried to SOQL on the KnowledgeArticleVersion? Please add your query so we can see it.

Comment: Select ID from KA_Template__kav where publishstatus = 'Archived' and language = 'en_US'... I don't feel wrong in the query ..! Because I have done the same for plenty of article types..! I was not able to figure out only for this article type actually..! Tat too only archived version was not getting retrieved.. Is there any permission related stuffs for archived alone..?